# Delphi7 TeeChart v4 Legend - How to Scroll?

Tags: delphi, charts, delphi-7, vcl, teechart

I have a `TChart` (Steema `TeeChart` included in Delphi IDE) component which may have up to 64 Chart Series (Stacked Area in my case). I need to display all existent series in chart, but Legend, unfortunately, doesn't show all of existing series, only some firsts of them 10-16 (see picture).  [image: Chart with 64 series]

Is it possible somehow to Scroll Legend for viewing all existing series?
If not directly maybe some workaround?

used Delphi7, Chart v4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my own implementation, based on `TChart.OnMouseWheel` event, simulating Legend scrolling (it is scrolled, but without any scroll bar - maybe it will be task for future):

```
procedure TForm1.Chart1MouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);

  function GetChartActiveSeriesCount(aChart: TChart): Integer;
  var
    iIdx: Integer;
  begin
    Result := 0;
    for iIdx := 0 to aChart.SeriesCount-1 do
    begin
      if aChart.Series[iIdx].Active = True then
        Inc(Result);
    end;
  end;

var
  lCliMousePos: TPoint;
  lActiveCount: Integer;
  lChart: TChart;
begin
  lChart := TChart(Sender);
  lCliMousePos := lChart.ScreenToClient(MousePos);
  if PtInRect(lChart.Legend.RectLegend, lCliMousePos) then
  begin
    if WheelDelta > 0 then
    begin
      if lChart.Legend.FirstValue > 0 then
        lChart.Legend.FirstValue := lChart.Legend.FirstValue-1;
    end
    else
    begin
      lActiveCount := GetChartActiveSeriesCount(lChart);
      if (lChart.Legend.FirstValue + lChart.Legend.NumRows) < lActiveCount then
      lChart.Legend.FirstValue := lChart.Legend.FirstValue+1;
    end;
  end;
  Handled := True;
end;
```

Also there are some tricks how to trigger `TChart.OnMouseWheel` event, because Tchart cannot get focus it is needed to play with Main Form `OnMouseWheel` event or `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` windows message. HowTos here: 
  http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2010/qt/delphi-redirect-mouse-wheel-control-under-the-mouse.htm or here: http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2010/qt/timage-handling-mouse-wheel-messages.htm

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible with the Professional edition of TeeChart. It includes the Legend ScrollBar tool (*TLegendScrollBar*) for this purpose. Fully functional evaluation versions can be downloaded [here](http://www.steema.com/download/vcl).

Comment: Thanks, @Narcís Calvet, but maybe some workarounds? 
Also please provide me a link, if it possible, HOW TO instruction for installation of PRO edition for Delphi7, because i didn't find it, but found that other people had some problems because of old version (included in Delphi7)

Comment: Generally, the Pro version installer backups and uninstalls the Standard version shipped with the IDE without problems. If you find any problem with it, please contact the support team (https://www.steema.com/licensing/support/?steema/licensing_support). Regarding a workaround for the legend scroll, have you tried the solution suggested here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21315439/509369

Comment: Hi @Yeray, Thanks. i will try installation. 
Regarding mentioned by You workaround - I tried it and it's working, moreover it was written by me :), but I asked if somebody have other, maybe better solution :)